# React How to update nested Array in api json?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this .json file that I used as an API/backend server. It goes like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Security 1",
    "price": [
      {
        "date": "01/01/19",
        "number": 1000
      },
      {
        "date": "01/02/19",
        "number": 900
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Security 2",
    "price": [
      {
        "date": "01/01/19",
        "number": 1050
      },
      {
        "date": "01/02/19",
        "number": 950
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I had built a form to update the price list every time a price is added. However, the way my application is built is that App.js is the parent component that lists the Securities, a Single Security Box .js file (a child file) that displays the individual data in each box. Within each box, there is a price button that pops up to add a new price, in which I created another file for (a grandchild file), called Price Form.js. I had successfully created an updated price list from Price Form.js. Now I'm attempting to update the price list in Single Security Box while updating the security list in App.js.

In **Price Form.js**, this updates the price list. I can see in my console when I tried to debug the errors, that an updated price list was submitted on the close button. I just need to send the updated price list to the single security box.

```
handleFormSubmit = e => {
  // prevents page refreshes on submission
  e.preventDefault();

  const { priceArr } = this.state;
  const { addPrice, handleEditPriceSubmission } = this.props;

  const fields = {priceArr};

  this.setState(() => {
      if (addPrice) addPrice(fields);
      else handleEditPriceSubmission(fields);
  });
  this.props.closePopup();
  console.log("submission", fields);
  console.log("Is this button working?");
};
```

**Single Security Box .js**

This is where I mapped to display the price list on popup.

```
<td>    
<button type="button" className="price-btn" onClick={this.togglePricePopup}>Prices</button>
          {this.state.showPricePopup ? (
           <PriceForm
             pricelist= {this.props.price}
             handleEditPriceSubmission={ this.handleEditPriceSubmission }
             addPrice={this.addPrice}
             closePopup= {this.togglePricePopup}
            />
     ) : null}
</td>
```

And I have the state properties in this same file. I added the console.log to see if the pricelist had changed when I submitted the updated pricelist from PriceForm.js.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        showPopup: false,
        showPricePopup: false, //don't show popup
        pricelist: this.props.price,
    };
    console.log("price list", this.state.pricelist);
  }
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can update this.state.pricelist. How do I do that? I'm trying to figure out solutions and I tried to look online for solutions but I got confused trying to understand lifting state up.

And then I'll need to update the security list in **App.js**. Here is where I display the securities list in **App.js**:

```
{this.state.list.map(props => (
     <SecurityBox
      {...props}
      key={props.id}
      securitylist = {this.state.list}
      editCurrentSecurity={this.editCurrentSecurity}
      deleteSecurity={this.deleteSecurity}
     />
 ))}
```

and the state properties in **App.js** are:

```
 state = {
    list: securitiesgroup,
    showPopup: false
  };
```

You can view my application in question at https://codesandbox.io/s/github/kikidesignnet/caissa. Also, one more thing to mention, since the Price List only allow one entry per day to add new prices, therefore, I thought that if necessary, I might need to use `date` as a special id to find the correct price list in the correct place as I did for Single security box when I was editing the data in each box, like this code in **App.js**

```
 editCurrentSecurity = editedSecurity => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      list: prevState.list.map(list =>
        list.id === editedSecurity.id ? { list, ...editedSecurity } : list
      )
    }));
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

The key for updating the data at the top level is going to be passing your `addPrice` function all the way down to `SingleSecurityBox` and `PriceForm`.

Think about it this way, at the top level you have `list`, which is the JSON object that you defined in your 'API'. This list is shared amongst all of your components as the source of truth for data.

To update the entire app, what you should do is pass a function to update `state.list` to any component that needs it.

The hierarchy you have current is:

`App.js` renders `SecurityBox` renders `PriceForm`

Right now, in `PriceForm`, you're actually doing the right thing in updating the price array with the new price. The problem is, you're not updating the source of truth for that particular security and saying: "This is your new price array".

What needs to happen would be something like:

1. You do as you currently are, and create a new array with the new price added to the end.
2. You pass that new price array *up* from `PriceForm` using `this.props.addPrice`
3. You pass the array up one more time from `SingleSecurityBox` using `this.props.addPrice`
4. In the root component, `App.js`, you then make the proper modifications to the `list` data structure to include the new price.

For example (not totally working code, you're going to have to make some modifications here)

```js
// PriceForm.js
  addPrice = newPrice => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      addPricePopup: !prevState.addPricePopup,
        // spreads out the previous list and adds the new price with a unique id
      priceArr: [...prevState.priceArr, { ...newPrice }]
    }), state => this.props.addPrice(securityId, state.priceArr);
  };
```

```js
// SingleSecurityBox.js
  <PriceForm
    pricelist= {this.props.price}
    handleEditPriceSubmission={ this.handleEditPriceSubmission }
    // Important change here
    addPrice={this.props.addPrice}
    closePopup= {this.togglePricePopup}
  />
```

```js
// App.js
addPrice(securityId, newPriceList) {
  // Update list here, replace securityId pricelist with new pricelist
}
// render()
 <SecurityBox
  {...props}
  key={props.id}
  // Important Change
  addPrice={this.addPrice}             
  securitylist = {this.state.list}
  editCurrentSecurity={this.editCurrentSecurity}
  deleteSecurity={this.deleteSecurity}
 />
```

Comment: I tried your code but it's not working... Can you show me your working code please?